# How to use jstl/functions and jstl/fmt in the same JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

i imported the two libraries `jstl/functions` and `jstl/fmt` in my JSP as follows:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
```

i attempt to use these 2 libraries for formatting date, get length of string
i have a problem when i run the page, the problem is:

```
 org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Attempt to redefine the prefix fn to    
 http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions, when it was already defined as     
 http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fn in the current scope
```

i tried to remove one and try to use its prefix instead of the other but it fails also, what is the main cause of that:

Comment: Maybe because exists another taglib fn? What happens if you change it to fnc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only time I encounter this issue is when I have both taglibs set with the prefix "fn", like this:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fn" %>
```

You clearly don't have this in your example, however I would venture a guess that you had it this way at some point and compiled the jsp. Now that you have fixed the issue, the page/project may need to be recompiled.

I've also encountered Tomcat "holding" old versions if you don't explicitly undeploy the application. This can be done in Netbeans by going to Services->Servers->{your tomcat instance}->Web Applications->{right click application name}->undeploy

You can also remove it from the Tomcat folder in the work directory and web apps folder to accomplish the same thing.